# Use same fragment multiple times in same activity/layout

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Not 100% on terminology so bear with me.

I have an activity that compares two items side by side, one on the left and another on the right. The items contain the same layout so I was wondering if I could reuse the left fragment java and XML file and instantiate a new instance. It is possible that I just copy and paste the left fragment files into identical files for right side but I feel as though there must be a more elegant method.

tdlr: Is there a way to make two or more instances of the same fragment operating in the same layout/activity?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to make a parent layout with 2 side-by-side containers (framelayout, for example or fragments directly).

If you prefer in code, then add the fragments through FragmentManager transation in those containers.

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
     .beginTransaction().add(R.id.left_container,new YourFragment(),"some tag1").commit();

    getSupportFragmentManager()
     .beginTransaction().add(R.id.right_container,new YourFragment(),"some tag2").commit();
```

Comment: Above is correct, to expand, If you want the same fragment to be 're-created' over and over inside the layout(slightly different use case, but related to what you are describing possibly), then that is possible too. You would just need to create a new instance and repeat the above method with (the only 1) desired container in its "new" place (same place as previous, but 'new' fragment instance)

Comment: Do I put this code in the onCreate of the main Activity?

Comment: Yes, but not before setContentView() :)

Comment: So right now I have the user input a number and press a button which retrieves the information. On the button press, the fragment passes the input to the main activity for processing. How can I distinguish where the button press is coming from and thus how to process the information?

Or if you have useful links which I could read that would be awesome as well.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html so make a callback method, that have a parameters that distinguish your fragment from other (you can pass this parameters as arguments when creating fragment)

Comment: Set onClickListener for the buttons from within fragment class then pass an id to a method in activity.  Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
              MainActivity.onFragmentButtonClick ( getTag());   
            }
        });

Comment: MainActivity has public method called  onFragmentButtonClick(String tag){ if(tag.equals("some tag1"))  //do something   }

Comment: @chiangy77 If you plan to use these fragments in other Activities, aelimill's answer is better. Callback interface will allow greater flexibility.